# TextView's of a Layout are overlapping

Tags: android, eclipse, layout, textview, overlap

I've a problem with a layout, I'm really stuck and I can't found the solution...

I've this layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/header_separator"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
  >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lbTitulo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="@string/detalles_label_titulo"
        android:width="60dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitulo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/lbTitulo"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/lbTitulo"
        android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lbFecha"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtTitulo"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/lbTitulo"
        android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="@string/detalles_label_fecha"
        android:width="60dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtFecha"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/lbFecha"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/lbFecha"
        android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lbDescuento"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/lbFecha"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtFecha"
        android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
        android:text="@string/detalles_label_descuento"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:width="100dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDescuento"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/lbDescuento"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/lbDescuento"
        android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lbLugar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtDescuento"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/lbDescuento"
        android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="@string/detalles_label_lugar"
        android:width="60dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtLugar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/lbLugar"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/lbLugar"
        android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lbDescripcion"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtLugar"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/lbLugar"
        android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="@string/detalles_label_descripcion"
        android:width="125dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDescripcion"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/lbDescripcion"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/lbDescripcion"
        android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6sp"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/imgFotoEvento"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtDescripcion"
        android:contentDescription="@string/detalles_foto_evento" 
        android:gravity="center" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

And the Graphical Layout show the field 'lbTitulo' and 'txtTitulo' in top, and just below the fields 'lbFecha' and 'txtFecha' but the other fields are overlapping above the fields 'lbFecha' and 'txtFecha' (all together lbFecha, lbDescuento, lbLugar, lbDescripcion)...

Could someone say me what i'm doing wrong?

Tyvm!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In these type of scenarios I create a layout within a layout.

So each line of yours will be a layout and hence. You can only those elements in that line.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="57dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
           android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:text="Name"
        android:textSize="20dp" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtName"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="left" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="57dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblName1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
           android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:text="Name"
        android:textSize="20dp" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtName1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="left" >

    </EditText>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: I'll try, that seems perfect. Anyway, the parameter layout_below have a  bug or I'm using it wrong?

Comment: working, tyvm! (however I don't know why dont worked)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use LinearLayout Instead of RelativeLayout...

Comment: So the 'layout_below' parameter of the childs is invalid, the text is dinamic, so I can't use the specific position, it's necesary that use below.

Comment: android:layout_below
 android:layout_alignLeft
android:layout_alignBaseline       
 android:layout_toRightOf this all not supported by LinearLayout

Comment: when the text grown calculate the new position is harder... I prefer don't assess this solution yet.